# Is communication in java rmi secure?

Tags: java, rmi

Is communication between clients and servers in java rmi secure (i.e. encrypted by default)?

Answer (score 13):

Encoded, yes. Encrypted, no.

JERI for JINI gives JRMP (the RMI protocol) over SSL, IIRC.

JSR #76 would have provided RMI Security, however it was controversially [voted down](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/results?id=325).

Comment: +1 You just blew the minds of those who that that the two words meant the same thing.

Comment: Given most computer security it would seem that a lot of programmers consider those word synonyms. ;) Or rather ;(

Comment: JERI for Jini gives JERI over SSL actually, or over plaintext of course javax.rmi.ssl gives JRMP over SSL. JERI is a different protocol from JRMP.

Answer (score 6):

I think you mean "encrypted" not "encoded". The answer is no. If you're using RMI in a non-trusted environment I would suggest something like [RMI over SSH tunneling](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2003/10/rmi-ssh_p1.html).

Answer (score 4):

By secure I guess you mean encrypted. Not by default with RMI. You can use [custom socket factories](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/socketfactory/index.html) to encrypt RMI comms.

Answer (score 3):

In short, no.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/faq.html#encryption

In essence, the network channel has to be encrypted if you need things to be secure.

Answer (score 1):

Not mentioned this far: You can set up a [VPN](http://www.google.com/search?q=vpn&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a) between the machines for full layer 2 security.