# RMI Support for Android

Tags: java, android, rmi

I am having an Android client and a Java Server. But I noticed that for a distributed application, RMI is needed but unfortunately not available for Android. I came across something called light weight RMI LipeRMI as a substitute. I don't know what exactly is the difference between Sun's RMI and LipeRMI? Does LipeRMI does the same job of Sun's RMI or does it have any limitation ?

Comment: "But I noticed that for a distributed application, RMI is needed" -- um, well, no. There are countless protocols for network communication, such as HTTP.

Comment: I think sending of complex object nets from one application to another, it's probably faster with RMI since it is in binary format usually keeping  bandwidth into account

Comment: I would go with socket based if that is possible than using third party library that I am not sure of if works.

Comment: Um, well, no. There are plenty of solutions for that, such as protobuf, Thrift, FlatBuffers, etc. Moreover, there has been much work done on securing other protocols, like HTTP, [than with RMI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314809/is-communication-in-java-rmi-secure). Also, RMI is Java-specific; you never know when your client or server is going to need to run something other than for some reason in the future.